# Newbie - What are the odds of having a birthday on a particular day of the week?

Tags: probability

Hope I'm in the right spot, moderators please move if not.

I turned 13 on Friday the 13th. I turned 20 on Friday the 13th. Today I turned 47 (Friday the 13th).

To me it seems odd to go so long (27 years) without a single Friday the 13th birthday. My uneducated guess would say that about every 7 years one would end up with a Friday (or any day of the week) birthday.

So what are the odds/ probability of having a birthday on a particular day of the week? Is it one in seven? If that's the case then perhaps my dice just rolled the way they did.

I did try to look to look this up, but everything I searched for gave results for the birthday problem / paradox. Thanks.

Comment: I can't find any logic that makes me think other than 1 in 7.

Comment: What about 13 February, 2009. Wasn't that a Friday? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/February_13

Comment: Also, 1998. But 27 years ago, Feb 13, 1988, was a Saturday.  Am I missing something?

Comment: @JeremyMiles - thanks. I think it's me that's missing something. So much for my memory :)

Comment: :) Happens to all of us.

Comment: Which day of the week a date falls on is not stochastic; you can calculate it for any year. How is this on topic?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think odds or probability are involved. The answer is determined by the number of days in a week (7) and the number of days in a year (365 or 366 on leap years), and the interval between leap years (usually 4 but sometimes it is 8, as there is no leap year day on some 00 years). So there is no chance involved. Just some bookkeeping to figure out which day on which year.

It also depends on what date range you are looking at. There are four year, 100 year, and 400 year cycles in deciding [when a year is a leap year](https://www.timeanddate.com/date/leapyear.html). So the distribution of days of week in your lifetime may not match the true average over few thousand years.